# Authorization error when parsing data from router

Tags: python, mechanize, router

I want to scrap the data from my router for some home automation, but im facing some trouble I cannot solve/crack.

I have managed to successfully login into the router, but when accessing the data with python script (opening links in router web interface) I recieve an error saying: You have no authority to access this router!

If I manually copy and paste url that python script is accessing into browser (with cookies set), the response is the same. But if i click the buttons inside router web interface i get no "authority" complains. Any ideas how to fix this?

here is the script:

```
import re
import mechanize
import cookielib

br = mechanize.Browser()

cookies = cookielib.LWPCookieJar()
br.set_cookiejar(cookies)
#they "encrypt" the username and password and store it into the cookie. I stole this value from javascript in runtime.
br.addheaders = [('Cookie','Authorization=Basic YWRtaW46MjEyMzJmMjk3YTU3YTVhNzQzODk0YTBlNGE4MDFmYzM=;')] 
#open connection to the router address
br.open('http://192.168.1.1/')
#the only form is "login" form (which we dont have to fill up, because we already have the cookie)
br.select_form(nr=0) 
br.form.enctype = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
br.submit() 

#then the router returns redirect script, so we have to parse it (get the url).
redirect_url = re.search('(http:\/\/[^"]+)',br.response().read()).group(1)
token = re.search("1\/([A-Z]+)\/",redirect_url).group(1) #url always has a random token inside (some kind of security?)

#So with this url I should be able to navigate to page containing list of DHCP clients
br.open("http://192.168.1.1/"+token+"/userRpm/AssignedIpAddrListRpm.htm")

print(br.response().read()) #But response contains html saying "You have no authority to access this router!".
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved the issue by adding this:

```
br.addheaders.append(
    ('Referer', "http://192.168.1.1/userRpm/LoginRpm.htm?Save=Save")
)
```

Reason:

Searching the message on web I navigated to a forum where users with firefox version (old) complained about the same warning. The fix was to enable the referrer to be sent, so I did the same in the script and it worked out.